# four-digit lock, use vwf to stimulate

Tags: vhdl

I want to design a four-digit lock. The password consists of four digits from 0 to 15. User can set the password and input the password serially. If the password input is correct, the output signal `Unlock` is '1', else `Err` is '1'.

Here is my code:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Lock is
    port(
        code: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        mode: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        CLK,RST: in std_logic;
        Unlock, Err: out std_logic
    );
    type password is array(3 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
end entity Lock;

architecture beh_lock of Lock is
    TYPE states IS (st0,st1,st2,st3,st4,st5,st6,st7,st8,st9);
    signal cur,nxt: states:=st0;
    signal my_pwd: password;
begin

    process(CLK,RST)
    begin
        if RST='1' then
            case Mode is
                when "00" => cur<=st1;
                when "01" => cur<=st6;
                when others => cur<=st0;
            end case ;
        elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
            cur<=nxt;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(cur)
    begin
        case cur is
            when st0=> Unlock<='0'; Err<='0';
            when st1=> nxt<=st2; my_pwd(0)<=code; Unlock<='0'; Err<='0';
            when st2=> nxt<=st3; my_pwd(1)<=code;
            when st3=> nxt<=st4; my_pwd(2)<=code;
            when st4=> nxt<=st9; my_pwd(3)<=code;
            when st5=> 
                if code=my_pwd(0) then nxt<=st6; 
                else nxt<=st0; Err<='1'; 
                end if;
            when st6=>
                if code=my_pwd(1) then nxt<=st7;
                else nxt<=st0; Err<='1';
                end if;
            when st7=> 
                if code=my_pwd(2) then nxt<=st8; 
                else nxt<=st0; Err<='1'; 
                end if;
            when st8=>
                if code=my_pwd(3) then nxt<=st9; Unlock<='1';
                else nxt<=st0; Err<='1';
                end if;
            when st9=> Unlock<='0';
            when others=> NULL;
        end case;
    end process;
end architecture beh_lock;
```

When I run the stimulation, something wrong appears. Why does the signal `Err` become high?

[image]

Comment: The waveform doesnt show the value of my_pwd. You also dont show the states. You also dont show the testbench. I suspect the waveform is from Quartus Simulator which uses post synthesis netlist. You also have missing signals in state machine sensitivity list. You also have latches generated for `my_pwd` ,`Err` and `Unlock` because you do not assign values in all states. To avoid latches, assign these values in a clocked process.

Comment: There aren't any modern FPGA families that provide flip flops that can both be set and reset asynchronously. You might want to use synchronous reset.  There are two states without next state assignments inferring latches for that as well as Unlock and Err. For outputs you can assign default values to signals earlier in a sequence of statements, a last assignment will supersede. [Your VHDL doesn't exhibit the Err using the waveform to create a testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxOA1.jpg).